# Print sum of Nth column at the header of file with existing rows bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have an input file with billions of records and a header.
Header consists of meta info, total number of rows and sum of the sixth column. I am splitting the file into small sizes, due to which my header record must be updated as the sum of sixth column and total rows is changed.

This is the sample record

filename: testFile.text

```
00|STMT|08-09-2022 13:24:56||5|13.10|SHA2
10|000047290|8ddcf4b2356dfa7f326ca8004a9bdb6096330fc4f3b842a971deaf660a395f65|18-01-2020|12:36:57|3.10|00004729018-01-20201|APP
10|000052736|cce280392023b23df2a00ace4b82db8eb61c112bb14509fb273c523550059317|07-02-2017|16:27:49|2.00|00005273607-02-20171|APP
10|000070355|f2e86d2731d32f9ce960a0f5883e9b688c7e57ab9c2ead86057f98426407d87a|17-07-2019|20:25:02|1.00|00007035517-07-20192|APP
10|000070355|54c1fc2667e160a11ae1dbf54d3ba993475cd33d6ececdd555fb5c07e64a241b|17-07-2019|20:25:02|5.00|00007035517-07-20192|APP
10|000072420|f5dac143082631a1693e0fb5429d3a185abcf3c47b091be2f30cd50b5cf4be11|14-06-2021|20:52:21|2.00|00007242014-06-20212|APP
```

Expected:

filename: testFile_1.text

```
00|STMT|08-09-2022 13:24:56||3|6.10|SHA2
10|000047290|8ddcf4b2356dfa7f326ca8004a9bdb6096330fc4f3b842a971deaf660a395f65|18-01-2020|12:36:57|3.10|00004729018-01-20201|APP
10|000052736|cce280392023b23df2a00ace4b82db8eb61c112bb14509fb273c523550059317|07-02-2017|16:27:49|2.00|00005273607-02-20171|APP
10|000070355|f2e86d2731d32f9ce960a0f5883e9b688c7e57ab9c2ead86057f98426407d87a|17-07-2019|20:25:02|1.00|00007035517-07-20192|APP
```

filename: testFile_2.text

```
00|STMT|08-09-2022 13:24:56||2|7.00|SHA2
10|000070355|54c1fc2667e160a11ae1dbf54d3ba993475cd33d6ececdd555fb5c07e64a241b|17-07-2019|20:25:02|5.00|00007035517-07-20192|APP
10|000072420|f5dac143082631a1693e0fb5429d3a185abcf3c47b091be2f30cd50b5cf4be11|14-06-2021|20:52:21|2.00|00007242014-06-20212|APP
```

I am able to split the file and calculate the sum but unable to replace the value in header part.
This is the script I have made

```
#!/bin/bash

splitRowCount=$1
transactionColumn=$2

filename=$(basename -- "$3")
extension="${filename##*.}"
nameWithoutExt="${filename%.*}"

echo "splitRowCount: $splitRowCount"
echo "transactionColumn: $transactionColumn"


awk 'NR == 1 { head = $0 } NR % '$splitRowCount' == 2 { filename = "'$nameWithoutExt'_" int((NR-1)/'$splitRowCount')+1 ".'$extension'"; print head > filename } NR != 1 { print >> filename }' $filename


 ls *.txt | while read line
 do
  firstLine=$(head -n 1 $line);
  awk -F '|'  'NR !=1 {sum += '$transactionColumn'}END {print sum} '   $line
 done
```

Comment: Thanks for nice question(putting efforts and samples), could you please also let us know what is the logic of dividing files/splitting files also? That will make it more clear, thank you(Not my downvote btw).

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 as I read the code, the file is split initially using variable `$splitRowCount` - which is set by first command line parameter in bash script. This creates a (probably large) amount of text files.  I wonder though if it's efficient to invoke awk for every single line in result files ? Can this process be done using only awk ?

Comment: @MyICQ After doing google i got awk command, so I tried with that.  `$splitRowCount` will be high values . It will create on an average 10 - 20 files.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Suppose the files is having 50 records, and if I pass the `splitRowCount `as 25 , then it will create 2 files with 25 records each and a header.

Comment: @MuddassirRahman, Sure, could you please do add sample of output file names along with info which is given your previous comment(how to get output files) that will make question more clear, cheers.

Comment: If the count of lines was lower - or if you have plenty of memory - you should be able to do it with awk in one go, using arrays.  But given already-split files, you can probably add headers simply by summarizing over the file with awk, print header to a file, and use `>>` operator to concatenate header and data ? This will prevent you from printing each individual line again when adding header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an `awk` solution for splitting the original file into files of `n` records. The idea is to accumulate the records until the given count is reached then generate a file with the updated header and the accumulated records:

```bash
n=3
file=./testFile.text

awk -v numRecords="$n"  '
    BEGIN {
        FS = OFS = "|"

        if ( match(ARGV[1],/[^\/]\.[^\/]*$/) ) {
            filePrefix = substr(ARGV[1],1,RSTART)
            fileSuffix = substr(ARGV[1],RSTART+1)
        } else {
            filePrefix = ARGV[1]
            fileSuffix = ""
        }

        if (getline headerStr <= 0)
            exit 1
        split(headerStr, headerArr)
    }
    (NR-2) % numRecords == 0 && recordsCount {
        outfile = filePrefix "_" ++filesCount fileSuffix
        print headerArr[1],headerArr[2],headerArr[3],headerArr[4],recordsCount,recordsSum,headerArr[7] > outfile
        printf("%s", records) > outfile
        close(outfile)
        
        records = ""
        recordsCount = recordsSum = 0
    }
    {
        records = records $0 ORS
        recordsCount++
        recordsSum += $6
    }
    END {
        if (recordsCount) {
            outfile = filePrefix "_" ++filesCount fileSuffix
            print headerArr[1],headerArr[2],headerArr[3],headerArr[4],recordsCount,recordsSum,headerArr[7] > outfile
            printf("%s", records) > outfile
            close(outfile)
        }
    }
' "$file"
```

With the given sample you'll get:

- `testFile_1.text`

```
00|STMT|08-09-2022 13:24:56||3|6.1|SHA2
10|000047290|8ddcf4b2356dfa7f326ca8004a9bdb6096330fc4f3b842a971deaf660a395f65|18-01-2020|12:36:57|3.10|00004729018-01-20201|APP
10|000052736|cce280392023b23df2a00ace4b82db8eb61c112bb14509fb273c523550059317|07-02-2017|16:27:49|2.00|00005273607-02-20171|APP
10|000070355|f2e86d2731d32f9ce960a0f5883e9b688c7e57ab9c2ead86057f98426407d87a|17-07-2019|20:25:02|1.00|00007035517-07-20192|APP
```

- `testFile_2.text`

```
00|STMT|08-09-2022 13:24:56||2|7|SHA2
10|000070355|54c1fc2667e160a11ae1dbf54d3ba993475cd33d6ececdd555fb5c07e64a241b|17-07-2019|20:25:02|5.00|00007035517-07-20192|APP
10|000072420|f5dac143082631a1693e0fb5429d3a185abcf3c47b091be2f30cd50b5cf4be11|14-06-2021|20:52:21|2.00|00007242014-06-20212|APP
```

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` code(Written and tested in GNU `awk`). Here I have defined `awk` variables named `fileInitials` which contains your output file's initial name eg: `testFile` then `extension` which contains output file's extension eg: `.txt` here. Then comes `lines` which will be your value on how many lines you want to have in a output file.

You need not to run shell + `awk` code, this could be done in a single `awk` like shown following.

```
awk -v count="1" -v fileInitials="testFile" -v extension=".txt" -v lines="3" '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" }
FNR==1{
  match($0,/^([^|]*\|[^|]*\|[^|]*\|[^|]*\|[^|]*)\|[^|]*(.*)/,arr)
  header1=arr[1]
  header2=arr[2]
  outputFile=(fileInitials count extension)
  next
}
{
  if(prev!=count){
    print (header1,sum header2 ORS val) > (outputFile)
    close(outputFile)
    outputFile=(fileInitials count extension)
    sum=0
    val=""
  }
  sum+=$6
  val=(val?val ORS:"") $0
  prev=count
  count=(++countline%lines==0?++count:count)
}
END{
  if(count && val){
     print (header1,sum header2 ORS val) > (outputFile)
     close(outputFile)
  }
}
'   Input_file
```

Comment: This is splitting the file but its not updating the header fields i.e sum and total row count. Its printing the same orginal header in each files

Comment: @MuddassirRahman, Let me quickly check and fix it.

Comment: @MuddassirRahman, Please try my updated code here. Written and tested in GNU `awk`, let me know how it goes, Cheers.